# Design tab for the xml layout in android studio

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a problem that drive me crazy, when I modify the code in the layout android application, and press the `design` tab to see the rendreing, it doesn't update and show the rendreing of before the modification, when I click in the `rendreing probleme`, they give this message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:166)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:206)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:131)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:394)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:337)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:366)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
>     at
>   com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>     at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)